# How do I include an external CSS file as a rule for a class inside a .scss file?

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I want to use `bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css` rules for only a particular section of my page. So, I downloaded it, created a new file called `bootstrap.scss` and tried to add this rule to it. I use django on my site, so I installed sass and added precompiler rules to my settings.

In my `bootstrap.scss` file, I added this rule to affect all `bs3` classes:

```
.bs3 {
  @include bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css;
}
```

`bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css` is in the same directory as `bootstrap.scss`, so I'm not sure if I still need to specify full path.

In my templates:

```
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.scss" %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<input id="example" type="submit" class="bs3 delBtn" value=" " rel='popover' data-placement='right' data-content='Some message'/>
```

The idea is to get that .scss file rules working only for elements with a class of bs3. As you have guessed, this isn't working. I don't see changes to that class whatsoever. But if I add `body{background-color: red;}` to bootstrap.scss, I can see that change, so I know that the scss file is being loaded.

I tried a couple of fixes from other stackoverflow questions, such as:

1. Using `import` instead of `include` - `@import "full/path/to/file.css"`
2. Using `import` without `.css` in the end of the file

Neither of those things worked. I am brand new to the world of SASS and I may have made some silly mistakes here. If you could point them out, that'd be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you import all the sass partials and wrap them in some type of namespace class:

```
.b3 {
    @import "/bootstrap-3.3.7-folder/_buttons.scss";
    @import "/bootstrap-3.3.7-folder/_grid.scss";
    @import "/bootstrap-3.3.7-folder/_somefile.scss";
    @import "/bootstrap-3.3.7-folder/_somefile.scss";
    @import "/bootstrap-3.3.7-folder/_etc.scss";
}
```

This will output all your bs-3.3.7 styles wrapped in `.bs3 {}`

```
.bs3 .btn {}
.bs3 .row {}
/* etc */
```

Then just wrap those elements

```
<div class="b3">
    <!-- all your 3.3.7 specific styles here -->
    <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: But I don't have all these files. I just have one `bootstrap-3.3.7.min.css` file. Where and how can I get these ones?

Comment: Github! I think they're all here. It's a good idea to have all of these partials for your build anyway: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/tree/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap

Comment: And here's the parent file for bs 3.3.7. You would basically have all these imports wrapped in `.bs3 {}` like my example above https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss

Answer (score 0):

**You can't include `css` file in `scss` file.**

There is a concept called **`partials`** in `scss`. This is a great way to **modularize** your CSS and help keep things easier to maintain.

A partial is simply a Scss file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like **`_partial.scss`**.

The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file.

Scss partials are used with the **`@import`** directive and no need to specify **file extension** while importing.

To include a scss file in another scss file, try the below code and see the comment in code also.

Example,

```
 /*`_variable.scss` partial file*/

 $greencolor: green;
 $orangecolor: orange;


/*`_style.sass` partial file*/

@import 'variable';    /*here `variable` is the file name, if it is inside a folder named `variable`, then it should be `@import 'variable/variable'`*/

body{
   background-color:$orangecolor;
}
```